# How to find line that is causing the error

Tags: laravel

I have just started using Laravel and cannot get my head around how it throws errors. It doesn't show the line where the error is so I don't know how to locate it. Can anyone help?

> htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View:
>   M:\webserver\www\app\views\products\admin\create.blade.php)

This file is incredibly long and I cannot see where this array is being sent.

It's obviously coming from a Form::text() but I am passing a null as the second param in all that I can see. Why doesn't Laravel simply tell me the line that is erroring. The error it puts out is no use to me.

Comment: Find the line number provided within the error message.

Comment: It gives you the line number to the Helper and not the actual custom function that caused the Helper function to error.

Comment: @Igo why u no accept? (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Answer (score 1):

check the error file:

```
app/storage/logs/laravel.log
```

you can watch changes in the file (on Mac and *NIX) using command line:

```
tail -f app/storage/logs/laravel.log
```

remember that the storage directory must be writable by the webserver/PHP process because it's used as scratch space (for blade views, logs, etc.)

Comment: The log will only display the same information the error page did. Does not tell you which line in the template file caused it.

Comment: This works for the main php files (controllers, models, etc). For template one needs to check for the particular view in `storage/framework/views/`. The error message gives the view filename.